# What is the most direct way to determine that the inner element should be displayed in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON structure which represents as hierarchical elements.
It looks like the following:

```
{
  "url":"http://docsetups.json",
  "partnerId":1,
  "fieldDefs":
  [
    {"roleName":"Make","roleId":1,
      "children":[{"roleName":"Invoice Number","roleId":11}]
    },
    {"roleName":"Model","roleId":2,
      "children":[
        {"roleName":"Manufacturer","roleId":21},
        {"roleName":"EquipmentCode","roleId":22},
        {"roleName":"EquipmentSSN","roleId":23}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Plunker**

I've have created a plunker at: http://plnkr.co/edit/betBR2xLmcmuQR1dznUK?p=preview

I am using ng-repeat to display this in elements as a hierarchy of elements like the following:

[image: collapsed hierarchical elements]

When I click on either element the entire structure expands and looks like the following:

[image: expanded hierarchical elements]

The code which renders the DOM is nice and easy and looks like the following:

```
<div  class="headerItem"  
    ng-class="{focus: hover}" 
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
    ng-mouseleave="hover = false"
    data-ng-click="vm.onClick(item.roleName)" 
      data-ng-repeat="item in vm.documentSetups.fieldDefs">{{item.roleName}}
    <div class="subItem" ng-show="vm.isVisible" 
      data-ng-repeat="subItem in item.children">[ ] {{subItem.roleName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**vm.isVisible**

The thing to focus on here is the subitem which has the ng-show="vm.isVisible" so that it only displays if that value is true.

**Show Only The Subitem of the Clicked Parent**

However, I'd like to only display the subitem when its parent item is clicked -- instead of showing all subitems like it does now.  Can someone offer a good way to do this?  I'm hoping to do it without a directive, because I am interested in whether or not this is possible without a directive or if the code is terribly convoluted in that case.

If you have a solution which includes creating a directive, please keep it as simple as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Not related, but why don't you use CSS `hover` selector instead of `ngClass`?

Comment: @simoned I am attempting to "Think Angular" so I'm trying to work within the Angular API and use it in every way the Angular API developers have intended.  Honestly I looked up how to do that here on StackOverflow and thought it looked good.  I could've done it as you suggest using the CSS hover, but when I saw the sample I just grabbed it.  Is it wrong?  Is it overcomplicated?  Maybe. I will go back and look at it again and see if I only need the CSS hover instead.  Thanks for your question.

Comment: I wouldn't say wrong, but if you use that `hover` parameter just to change the style, that's what CSS is for. Don't overthink it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Oleksii**  You're answer is very close and it did inspire me to develop the following answer so I appreciate your input and I did upvote you.  However, there's a bit more to it than what you gave me.

**View Solution at Plunker**

I forked the previous plunker and you can see the final solution at:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QvyHlLh83bEyvlNkskYJ?p=preview

**No Directive Required**

Now I can click either or both element and they expand independently. Here's the sample output:
[image: solution view]

It took a bit of thinking, but what I did first was create a new type which holds a roleName (consider it unique) and a isVisible boolean. I call that type visibleItem and it looks like this:

```
var visibleItem = function (roleName){
          this.isVisible = false;
          this.roleName = roleName;
        };
```

After that I created an array to hold all the visibleItems (1 for each node):

```
var visibleItems = [];
```

Now when I load the json I go ahead and create 1 visibleItem object for each node and push it into the visibleItems array.

```
$http.get('items.json')
  .success(function(data, status, header, config) {
      vm.documentSetups=data; 
      for (var x = 0; x < vm.documentSetups.fieldDefs.length; x++)
      {
        visibleItems.push(new visibleItem(vm.documentSetups.fieldDefs[x].roleName));
      }
  })
```

They are "keyed" by their roleName (consider it unique).

Next, I had to write two helper methods (setVisibleItem and getVisibleItem)

```
 function setVisibleItem(roleName)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < visibleItems.length;x++)
        {
          if (visibleItems[x].roleName == roleName)
          {
            visibleItems[x].isVisible = !visibleItems[x].isVisible;
          }
        }
    }

  function getVisibleItem(roleName)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < visibleItems.length;x++)
        {
          if (visibleItems[x].roleName == roleName)
          {
            return visibleItems[x].isVisible;
          }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Wire Up The Helper Methods**

Finally, I wire up the setVisibleItem to the ng-click of the element and I wire up the getVisibleItem to the ng-show directive.

```
 data-ng-click="vm.onClick(item.roleName)" 
    data-ng-repeat="item in vm.documentSetups.fieldDefs">{{item.roleName}}
  <div class="subItem" ng-show="vm.getVisibleItem(item.roleName)" 
      data-ng-repeat="subItem in item.children">[ ] {{subItem.roleName}}</div>
  </div>
```

**Summary Of How It Works**

Basically each of those just iterates through the list and checks to insure if the roleName sent in matches the roleName of the item.  If it does it sets or gets the value.

**Solved Without a Directive and Not Bad**

It's a lot more work than you think it'll be, but I didn't have to implement a directive and the code is still fairly basic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define a flag for every item which determine if the item is open.
Then you pass the item itself into handler:

```
data-ng-click="vm.onClick(item)
```

after that - you simply need to invert isOpen flag:

```
function onClick(item)
{
    item.isOpen = !item.isOpen;
}
```

The whole view snippet:

```
<div class="headerItem"  
      ng-class="{focus: hover}" 
      ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
      ng-mouseleave="hover = false"
      data-ng-click="vm.onClick(item)" data-ng-repeat="item in vm.documentSetups.fieldDefs">{{item.roleName}}
   <div class="subItem" ng-show="item.isOpen" data-ng-repeat="subItem in item.children">[ ] {{subItem.roleName}}</div>
</div>
```

The plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/N8mUZaVfmLpnlW4kxzSr?p=preview